# Selenium webdriver design document

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to write an automation framework for embedded device User Interface(e.g. VoIP phones). These devices have different UI but logically performs the same actions.

After my analysis, it seems to be like, I would be developing a framework similar to selenium webdriver. Selenium webdriver works for various browsers whereas this framework will work for different embedded devices UI.

I am trying to understand the implementation of selenium webdriver. I have gone through its javadocs and source code, but I feel it will be better to have a design document for it.

Please let me know if you have a link for it.

Appreciate your help!!

PS: I will be developing this framework in Python/Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simon Stewart, the guiding force behind WebDriver, wrote a [chapter on its design and architecture](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html) for [The Architecture of Open Source Applications](http://www.aosabook.org/en/index.html).  It goes into great detail on how and why things are done.  You can also find good information in the Selenium Project's [JsonWireProtocol wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol), which describes the formal protocol spoken between a client (scripter) and a server (browser).  The [W3C standardization process for WebDriver](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) will some day be useful as the definitive reference, but it's barely just begun, and there is lots of stuff currently not defined in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the Selenium 2.0 working draft submitted to W3C...it's similar to High level design doc with most of the functional logic explained.

Please refer to this link:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webdriver-20120710/

Comment: It's WAY to early to try to understand WebDriver from that spec.  Very little of the reality is represented there yet.  But someday, yes, this will be the correct answer.

Comment: I completely agree that it's incomplete and hence mentioned as **Working draft** in my answer...but this Working draft itself explains few webdriver things in clear functional way (non-technical)...nothing completely irrelevant to the topic be rated as negative.

Comment: As one of the only folks to submit review comments on the spec, I'd agree with you.  +1, my error.

Comment: Thanks mate for giving a thought :-)